# jQuery.ajax() and sending boolean request arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url : uri,
  type : 'post',
  data : {someBooleanVar1: false, subVar: {someBooleanVar2: true}}
});
```

The problem is that on server someBooleanVar1 and someBooleanVar2 will be received as strings "false" and "true", but not as "0" and "1". Is there any way to **automatically** convert boolean arguments to "1" and "0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fixed version of @jcubic Answer:

```
function convertBoolToNum(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(i) {
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            convertBoolToNum(this);
        }
        else if (typeof obj[i] == 'boolean') {
            obj[i] = Number(obj[i]);
        }
    });
}

$.ajax = (function($ajax) {
  return function(options) {
    convertBoolToNum(options.data);
    return $ajax(options);
  };
})($.ajax);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should automatically convert booleans values to numbers in data options.

```
$.ajax = (function($ajax) {
  return function(options) {
    if (options.data != undefined) {
       for (var i in options.data) {
          if (options.data.hasOwnProperty(i) && 
              (typeof options.data[i] == "boolean")) {
            options.data[i] = Number(options.data[i]);
          }
       }
    }           
    return $ajax(options);
  };
})($.ajax);
```

Comment: Very good idea! There is only one mistake that conversion object is not recursive, so it will not work with {var: {subVar: false}}. I have fixed it, see me answer below.

Answer (score 1):

i know this post is a bit old but i still wanted to pass this information ^^
i pass vars to php and catch them with:

```
filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
```

like this i turn strings into booleans **`true=1`** and **`false=`**
false as string is empty in php

maybe i read the question wrong. but this is what i understood :)
with the code above you can easy build a function and add more filters to get everything work as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really automatically but adding 0 will convert the boolean to 0 or 1:

```
data : {someBooleanVar1: false + 0, someBooleanVar2: true + 0}
```

Comment: So I will need to do it every time passing some argument that can be boolean? No Thanks!

Comment: @Senior What do you expect? Some sort of global JS setting that will cause booleans to become 1 or 0??

Comment: May be there are some very custom options/methods in jQuery for this case. May be there is a short javascript code that can do this conversion automatically.

Comment: And what did you expected when posted your answer? You think that me and other developers don't know how to convert boolean var to number?

Comment: SeniorDev, you're rude. You started to be rude at 'No Thanks'. You were offered a free piece of advice. You're of course free to refuse it but respecting the guy who took from his own time to provide some help is the least you can do. BTW, I didn't know that true + 0 is one. And I guess I'm part of these 'other developers' you're talking about.

Comment: @Serge I'm sorry, I did not want to be so "rude". But I did not ask just about conversion from boolean value to number. By the way, converting like "false + 0" is bad advice, much better is to use "Number(false)".

Comment: @Senior good luck, I won't waste any more of your precious time.

Comment: @Shadow Thank you for your answer. I just can give you advice for more short bool->number conversion like "data : {someBooleanVar1: +false, someBooleanVar2: +true}". I hope you will like it.

Comment: @SeniorDev Appending a `+` to a variable *is* the usual method to type coerce things to `Number` in JavaScript; Appending `!!` for coercion to `Boolean`. JavaScript sources need to be transmitted over the internet, so terseness counts

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for Yi Jiang's answer. If you call ajax and don't have data set it gives an error. Added a test to see if the data property is set before converting the booleans. I used underscore, feel free to swap it out with the native js function hasownprop...

```
function convertBoolToNum( obj ) {
  $.each( obj, function( i ) {
    if ( typeof obj[i] == 'object' ) {
      convertBoolToNum(this);
    }
    else if ( typeof obj[i] == 'boolean' ) {
      obj[i] = Number( obj[i] );
    }
  } );
}

$.ajax = ( function( $ajax ) {
  return function( options ) {
    if ( _.has( options, 'data' ) ) { 
      convertBoolToNum( options.data );
    }  
    return $ajax( options );
  };
} )( $.ajax );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an even more optimized version that doesn't pollute the global namespace, converts values recursively, takes care of the potential undefined *data* property, and uses the proper method for converting boolean values to their corresponding integer values.

```
$.ajax = (function($ajax) {
    return function(options) {
        (function (obj) {
            var _fn = arguments.callee;
            $.each(obj, function(i) {
                if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
                    _fn(this);
                } else if (typeof obj[i] == 'boolean') {
                    obj[i] = ~~obj[i];
                }
            })   
        })(options.data || {});
        return $ajax(options);
    };
})($.ajax);
```

I still think it's quite shocking that this isn't performed internally by jQuery before it sends the request.